# Выбор хостинга для браузерной онлайн игры

Tags: хостинг

Уважаемые знатоки, помогите советом..
Заканчиваю многопользовательскую онлайн игру и задумался о выборе хостинга. html, css, js, jquery, php, mysql и прочие "радости" в одном флаконе.
Что нужно знать для того чтобы сделать правильный выбор? И какие есть подводные камни?
Буду благодарен за ваши советы.
P.S. хостинг буду брать сразу на год, а там как карта ляжет)

Comment: Советую не брать на год и не брать хостинг, а брать сразу VPS. Надо примерно понимать какую нагрузку генерит приложение и исходить из этого. 

Если игра динамическая и с mysql то первая проблема должна возникнуть с ним)

Comment: да, динамика с mysql.. какая именно проблема? и хз какую нагрузку будет генерить вся эта история и самое главное как определить эту нагрузку

Comment: Как вариант - взять любой сервер и дать немного поработать - измерить нагрузку.